# Batch render sprites with Spritekit

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm learning ios game programming and I need to create my own tile background - we're migrating an infinite-map style game from java.

I have the following code rendering our background tile graphics inside a loop:

```
SKSpriteNode *sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"shallow_1.png"];
sprite.position = CGPointMake(x,y);
[self addChild:sprite];
```

However, I'm trying to find out how to properly batch render in spritekit. In java/opengl we'd apply the texture, add all the render positions, and then render everything at once - saving performance.

How can I properly batch render these tiles using spritekit? I can't find any information.

Comment: You can use SKTextureAtlas to preload textures, use zPosition to draw layers at once. That should help.

Comment: batching is automatic - if consecutive child sprites use the same texture and blend mode they will be batch drawn. Enable the debug labels to see # of draw calls

Comment: Ok, so is there no harm then in calling `SKSpriteNode *sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"shallow_1.png"];` every single iteration of the loop? Seems unnecessary and in another languages we'd load it once, and clone. In opengl we apply the texture once, and just pass a list of vertices.

Comment: Seems like there is. Rendering a full background of these tiles (about 170 nodes) drops the FPS to 40.

Answer (score 0):

If you're planning to work with tilemaps, your best bet is KoboldKit.

It's a game engine for SpriteKit, and adds [several features](http://wiki.koboldkit.com/display/KKD/Features+and+Requirements) to the framework.

In includes support for time maps ([Tiled Map Editor](http://www.mapeditor.org/)).

Comment: That looks useful, it says it supports tilemaps without a size limit but "tilemap" usually refers to a fixed size, or infinite-horizontal. Does it support noise-generated, chunked tiling in all directions?

Comment: noise generation is something you need to do yourself in code. As long as you can generate something that the tile map component can understand, you should be good.

Comment: you you want an "infinite" tile map... that might be tricky. You could be better off with a separate questions about the best strategies to achieve that (e.g. moving your characters across separate adjacent tile maps).

Answer (score 0):

Load your texture once:

```
SKTexture *texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"shallow_1.png"];
```

Then, make all of your `SKSpriteNode` objects referencing that texture:

```
// inside loop
SKSpriteNode *node = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:texture];
```